# alternative to matrix inverse

Tags: matrices

I have 3 matrix X,Y,Z and the relation $$X.Z = Y$$

I know X and Y, need to compute Z.

I cannot compute $$Z = X^{-1}*Y$$ because X and Y are not square.

Example (computed in GF2, so 1+1=0):
$X=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
$Y=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$
$Z=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a way to compute Z from X and Y ?

Comment: Just solve the linear equations in the entries of $Z$, from $XZ=Y$ over $\Bbb F_2$. This is very easy. The result is your $Z$. As you said yourself, it was computed.

Comment: There is also the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).